# "My availability for the next two weeks (is/are) as follows"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Which is correct?

> My availability for the next two weeks are as follows

OR

> My availability for the next two weeks is as follows

I'm confused because I don't know if I should focus on the word "availability" which is singular or "two weeks" which is plural.

Answer (score 6):

Since the subject of the sentence, *my availability*, is singular, you need to use *is*. The phrase *for the next two weeks* is just additional information describing *my availability*. It should have no bearing whatsoever on your choice of whether to use a singular or plural verb. That kind of choice is always governed by the actual subject of the sentence. Take a look at the following examples:

> **That book** over there with yellow pages **is** mine.

The subject is singular, so the main verb of the sentence should also be singular in form.

> **The dogs** that live in the red house across the street **are** not there.

The subject is plural, so the main verb of the sentence should also be plural in form.

So, use *is*:

> **My availability** for the next two weeks **is** as follows...